# Creating Android application with 'core'

Tags: java, android

I'm learning android, and I don't quite understand the structuring.

I have to load a lot of data from the server using HTTP, but I need to pass the data to other activities. I was able to do this with Intent, but I have large objects of data and it seems like there should be a way to create a 'main' class, that contains all the other classes and new activities will be able to work with the 'main' class directly, instead of passing data from one activity to another, or is this the correct way of doing this? Thanks.

Basically what I want to do is this:

Main Class

```
    class Core 
    {
       public api;
       public acconts;
    }
```

Main Activity initializes Core class and calls the data loader functions. Then second activity is started.

Second activity can access Core.api and Core.accounts directly.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class like that in your project:

```
public class StorageManager
{
    private static StorageManager sInstance;
    private String mSomeData;

    public static StorageManager getInstance()
    {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new StorageManager();
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    private StorageManager()
    {

    }

    public String getData()
    {
        return mSomeData;
    }

    public void setData(String data)
    {
        mSomeData = data;
    }
}
```

"mSomeData" will contain the data that you want to pass among activities. You can also change String type to some other type or add more data fields. Then in any activity you can do this:

```
StorageManager.getInstance().setData("data1");
```

or

```
String data = StorageManager.getInstance().getData();
```

Comment: What's the benefit of having a singleton class? Couldn't you just say `static mSomeData` and call `data = StorageManager.mSomeData`?

Comment: You can but singleton class is cleaner and you can put it in a separate .java file so that it is clear that this is a separate functionality that is not associated with any activity but any activity can use it. In the future you can also easily extend this and for example add more methods like saving/reading data to/from sdcard. I would use this pattern for maintainability and scalability reasons. If you start just adding static variables to your code in random places your code will become harder than necessary to understand.

Comment: If there is a need of a static variable then I would just "hide" it behind a singleton like that and put the functionality related to it in a separate file. The rest of the code should not directly interact with static variables. In my opinion it makes the code harder to understand and is source of bugs.